# Como capturar assembly de classes que herdam de uma única classe?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, herança, reflexão

Tenho inúmeras classes.

Todas herdam de uma única classe

```
public abstract class ClasseBase 
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

e demais classes:

```
public class Teste1 : ClasseBase{ } public class Teste2 : ClasseBase { }
```

Precisaria capturar todos os assemblys das classes que herdam de ClasseBase

Como poderia fazer isso ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando LINQ dá para fazer isto:

```
var lista = (from arquivo in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                   from tipo in arquivo.GetTypes()
                   where typeof(ClasseBase).IsAssignableFrom(tipo)
                   select tipo).ToArray();
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/vAqvd9). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vDOAaH). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/GetAssemblies.cs).

Com LINQ usando expressões *lambda* (criado pelo AP Rod):

```
var teste = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Select(x => x.GetTypes()) 
                .SelectMany(x => x).Where(x => typeof(ClasseBase).IsAssignableFrom(x))
                .ToArray();
```

Sem LINQ:

```
foreach(var arquivo in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) {
    foreach (var tipo in arquivo.GetTypes()) {
        if (typeof(ClasseBase).IsAssignableFrom(tipo)) {
            Console.WriteLine(tipo);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2RdQWJ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7FSuEb). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/GetAssemblies2.cs).

Comment: é isso mesmo que eu queria, obrigado, porém estou tentando adaptar sem utilizar LINQ, mas mesmo assim, obrigado.

Comment: Tem o Resharper? Ele ajuda fazer isto. Eu não tenho trabalhado com C# há algum tempo então não tenho todas as ferramentas para facilitar o trabalho. Claro que dá para fazer manual também, não é complicado.

Comment: o meu Resharp expirou hoje, mas eu vou tentar fazer manualmente mesmo, obrigado

Comment: Feito na mão rapidinho.

Comment: fiz em lambda também, adiciona na sua resposta, que aí fica mais completa, para quem algum dia vier procurar, código:       var teste = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Select(x => x.GetTypes())
        .SelectMany(x => x)
        .Where(x => typeof(ClasseBase).IsAssignableFrom(x)).ToArray();

Answer (score 3):

Assim:

```
Type[] types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
foreach (Type type in types)
{
    if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ClasseBase)))
    {
        // Faça aqui o que você precisa. A classe encontrada está em "type".
    }
}
```